# Command line tool to adjust X server settings while running

Tags: networking, display, xorg

Is there a command line tool that allows you to adjust the settings for a running X session?

For example, the equivalent for pulseaudio would be the `pacmd` command line utility which allows you to add/edit/delete audio devices.

I'm asking because I've got a setup using Xdmx connecting several networked screens together, and I would like to know if theres a way to add and remove screens without too much effort

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `xrandr` command.

Here's some extra content just to get past the stupid 30-character minimum for posting.

Comment: cheers; turns out it doesn't support work with Xdmx but it's pointed me in the right direction :) I'll leave the question open for a couple of days to see if anyone else answers but thanks :D